# Настройка карусели в Bootstrap'e

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Вот карусель из Bootstrap:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Нужно что бы карусель появлялась без левого и правого контролера и индикатор, но после того как будет наведен курсор на карусель они появлялись. У меня получается только скрыть какой-либо контролер, но он появляется только когда я навожу курсор на его область. 
Вот пример как нужно http://bootstraplovers.com/templates/boland-shop-v1.1/index.html

Comment: Добавьте воспроизводимый пример, подключив необходимые библиотки бутстрапа

Comment: В примере не то, что вы объяснили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При наведении на карусель отображайте все:

```css
.carousel-control,
.carousel-indicators {
  display: none;
}


.carousel:hover .carousel-control,
.carousel:hover .carousel-indicators {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="Los Angeles">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200" alt="Chicago">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/200" alt="New York">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное.